# SQLite or something else?

Tags: android

I am trying to decide on what data storage methods to implement. Here is the situation. Whatever method I choose, it is going to be updated once week (can I update a SQLite db without putting out an update in the market?). The user cannot add or remove items from this ListActivity, they can only pick the ones they want. This data method should be able to remember the selected items during any given week. Let me know what method you would use and why. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A webservice would allow you to update the data whenever you want without having to push updates to the market. And updating your app in the market doesn't guarantee that users will apply the update. Ofcourse the downside here is that your users would need to be connected to the internet while using the app.

Comment: Lets assume that they will have the internet at some point but not all the time. Do they need to be connected to the internet at any time they want to access the database, or just while the data base is updating (if no, is there anything that acts like that?).

Comment: You could have the database refreshed when they are connected to the internet. The data could still be stored locally in a sqlite database. This way the users would not need to be connected to the internet while using the app. I don't have a specific example off the top of my head, however think about a todo list app that holds the data locally and then occasionally syncs to a server on the internet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Moving your database to remote server will give you freedom to manipulate data without actual application being updated, thus no need to update on the market. If it is a matter of access to internet, you can still use this practice, just more work has to be done (adding Broadcasters that will listen to connectivity than update the local database with global one on your server, or something similar).

Comment: Lets assume that they will have the internet at some point. Do they need to be connected to the internet at any time they want to access the database, or just while the data base is updating (if no, is there anything that acts like that?).

Comment: You use the connectivity just to update the phone (local) database with the data from global database, let say you are retrieving all the data in background thread and you write the  local database in the same background thread whenever there is connection available. (Implementation scenario)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the data on the device once a week, then you will need to use the local SQLite database and interact with a web service that provides the updates.  You will not need to go through the market to do this.  However, if you need to update the structure of the database (add, remove, or change columns or tables for example), then you will need to update your app on the market.

I highly recommend watching the Google IO 2010 talk [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html).  The speaker is the author original author of the Twitter app for Android, and talks about the design patterns and best practices that he uses.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was hoping I would be able to do. I appreciate your time.